# Python Unable to parse json keys

Tags: python, json

I have the following json (I've stripped a lot of the data out for simplicity):

```
{u'_links': [{u'uri': u'http://url/polling/v1/c1b1a360-1c69-49e0-9114-f02e3697e3ea', u'rel': u'header', u'methods': [u'GET', u'POST', u'PUT', u'OPTIONS']}, {u'uri': u'http://url/polling/v1/c1b1a360-1c69-49e0-9114-f02e3697e3ea/stores', u'rel': u'self', u'methods': [u'GET', u'PUT', u'POST', u'DELETE', u'OPTIONS']}], u'data': [{u'status': u'C2001', u'stackTrace': None, u'receivedIdx': 53713, u'description': u'Staged', u'timeChanged': u'2017-07-12T07:00:11.949-0400', u'storeNbr': u'1280', u'_links': [{u'uri': u'http://url.com/polling/v1/c1b1a360-1c69-49e0-9114-f02e3697e3ea/stores/1280', u'rel': u'self', u'methods': [u'GET', u'POST', u'DELETE', u'OPTIONS']}
```

I'm trying to get the "timeChanged" and "description" fields out of it.

```
data = json.loads(result.read())
for status in data:
  print "[",status['timeChanged'],"]", status['description']
```

results in:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That's not JSON you have. That's Python's `dict` representation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new with json and Python.  The "json" is the string I get when I print out what was in "data".

Comment: That string you get when you `print data` is the string representation of a `dict`, which is what randomir is trying to tell you. In other words, `data` is a `dict` (which makes sense because you are deserializing a JSON object when you call `json.loads`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `data = json.loads(result.read())` gives you the following dict:

```
{"foo": "bar", "baz": 3}
```

What happens when you iterate over a dict like this?

```
for x in data:
    print x
```

You get this:

```
foo
baz
```

The for loop iterates over the keys of the dictionary. Hence your `TypeError` when you try to subindex with a string on a string. You want something like this:

```
for x in data:
   status = data[x]
   ...
```

Well, maybe. I am confused about your example data, but you should understand the principle now.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me just what I needed.  I needed to get the value from the "data" key, and they print the 'field' from that data key.  In this case

for x in data["data"]
  print x['timeChanged', x['description']

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get the value from the "data" key, and then print the 'field' from that data key. In this case

```
for x in data["data"]:
   print x['timeChanged', x['description']
```